# Sorted pointer to a list in python

Tags: python

I've lurked on this site for a while, but this is my first ever question.  So go easy on me.

In python, I want to take a list of numbers and generate a sorted index into that list.

For example: `value = [-3 1 4 -1]`, then the sorted index (assuming ascending sort) should be = `[0 2 3 1]`

How do I generate this sorted index?  I need to use this sorted index to modify another list.

Comment: what do  you mean with "sorted pointer"? Sorted indices?

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers, maybe you mean positional indexes?  If you have been lurking like you say then you would know that we expect to see what you have tried.

Comment: For small lists, you could probably get away with something like `indexList = [value.index(item) for item in sorted(value)]`, but there's certainly more performant solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it using pure Python would be this:

```
values = [-3, 1, 4, -1]

values = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(values), key=lambda i: i[1])]
print(values)
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: The earlier method using numpy.argsort should have worked but threw an error in my setup.  This one did work.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution does not answer asked question (as you can see you did not get desired output). Your solution for input vector `x` gives vector `a` where `a[i] = index of sorted(x)[i] in x` while desired output would be `index of x[i] in sorted(x)`

Comment: @Drecker the OP wants to sort the list in ascending order, the result of which is `[-3,-1,1,4]`. If you take the indices of these values from the initial list, you will get `[0, 3, 1, 2]`. I think the OP should clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

This is elegantly done with standard Python library functions:

```
values = [-3, 1, 4, -1]

i_sorted = sorted(range(len(values)), key=lambda i: values[i])
print(i_sorted)

# The next 3 lines rearrange the array to address Drecker's comment
i_order = [None] * len(i_sorted)
for n, k in enumerate(i_sorted):
   i_order[k] = n
print(i_order)

[0, 3, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 3, 1]
```

Drecker is correct that my solution didn't answer the question. I added three lines of code to rearrange the list after the sort.  Not so elegant any more, but I can't see a better solution.

Comment: This solution does not answer asked question (as you can see you did not get desired output). Your solution for input vector `x` gives vector `a` where `a[i] = index of sorted(x)[i] in x` while desired output would be `index of x[i] in sorted(x)`

Comment: @Drecker Right you are, thanks for spotting that.  I edited my code accordingly.  For some reason this seems to be a hard little problem to solve cleanly.

Answer (score -1):

Let try with this:

```
import numpy as np
value = [-3, 1, 4, -1]
np.argsort(value)
```

Comment: Sweet, yea that's what I need.  I looked up sorting all over the place and it just showed how to print out sorted arrays.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is argsort just for integers?  Or float?  I get "builtins.TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index"

Comment: @BrianKorsedal If it's ok, give me a check :)

Comment: It's ok with float

Comment: What's wrong with your numpy, I run ok with this example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghfsm.png

Comment: All sorts of things could be wrong.  I'm remote debugging code running on python embedded within the Blender app.  Maybe there is an issue with Blender's python or an issue with the remote debugging or how I've set everything up.  I'll look into this.

Comment: This solution does not answer asked question (as you can see you did not get desired output). Your solution for input vector `x` gives vector `a` where `a[i] = index of sorted(x)[i] in x` while desired output would be `index of x[i] in sorted(x)`